# PHPUnit: Asserting exception objects are equal

Tags: php, phpunit

I am struggling to find a method to cleanly compare exceptions thrown in the code with one another. I have tried using `expectExceptionObject` but I am facing the limitation that `expectExceptionObject` only compares the class name, message and code:

```php
public function expectExceptionObject(\Exception $exception): void
{
    $this->expectException(get_class($exception));
    $this->expectExceptionMessage($exception->getMessage());
    $this->expectExceptionCode($exception->getCode());
}
```

This poses a limitation where I want to assert if the previous exception is passed correctly or when I extend an exception to include custom properties. I therefore use the following as workaround for this limitation:

```php
public function test()
{
    // Prep would normally be present here ...

    try
    {
        $controller->get();
        $this->fail('Failed asserting an exception was thrown');
    }
    catch (\Throwable $exception)
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            $exception,
            new BadRequestException(
                'sample-error-code', // This would write to a private property
                $previousException   // This would write to the $previous parameter on the standard Exception object
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This approach seems cluttered. Surely there is a way that achieves the same, yet is more clean and concise. A single-lined solution in which the power of `assertEquals()` (or `assertSame()` if the referenced object is has to be identical) together with `expectException()` or `expectExceptionObject()` is what I'm looking for. Does anybody know if such a method exists or is planned for in the future?

Comment: You either relate to the build-in assertions - and yes, they can be limited from time-to-time - or you encode the assertion your own (like with a try-catch, IMHO as you're looking clearly for an Exception, \Throwable is widening that too much). If you're looking for a middle-ground, consider a base test-case class in your test-suite that provides common assertions as methods. You can further extend Phpunit with own assertions as well. - Forgot to ask: Does this answer your question already?

Comment: Would you have any recommendations to read up on writing a custom "expectation"? I am familiar with writing custom assertions, but have never written a custom expectation and am also doubting if this is possible in a practical way due to the order of execution. And yes, this answers my question to a certain degree that this isn't possible right out of the box :)

Comment: An _Expectation_ is very similar to an _Assertion_ as it is an assertion, that is done after the test has passed (or more correctly: after the moment you $this->expect() something). From what I remember personally this is not that straight forward to do (compared to an assertion that is just called), however Phpunit sources are available and you can take a peek for starters how expectException() and the likes are implemented. So that should be the best place to read up on writing custom "expectations". Just take the original ;)

Comment: And to add, the way you started I think is right. First write the test within a concrete test case method. Make the catch/try the best you can imagine first. Then think about how you can scale that assertion/(sub-)test/expectation to where you need it.